# Node.js with Visual Studio 2012 for Web

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, ntvs

Does the new node.js plugin for Visual Studio work with Express Versions or with the integrated shell? As far as I know, the F# tools work in integrated shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be no, but they think of it. https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/workitem/520

Comment: VS Express 2013 for Web now supports NTVS. There is no support for 2012 Express, however.